# Any idea what happened to /Library/Receipts in Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: install, macos, pkg

Does anyone know why all the .bom files in /Library/Receipts moved to /var/db/receipts?

Comment: The short, simple answer is that someone at Apple decided that this should be done, and it was done. This is often referred to as an implementation detail, though. Is there a problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The man page is lame though. `man 5 bom` still says "The bill of materials for installed packages are found within the package receipts located in /Library/Receipts" even on OS X 10.9.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, `/var/db` on unix is *the* location for stuff like that.
second, it's much easier to type as it is in lower case.

so, not so unreasonable decision by apple's engineers.

Answer (score 1):

Receipts are in `/var/db`, but in my opinion it´s a bad decision because if someone backup `/system` to keep all applications data now receipts are not there any more.

It seems more and more difficult to keep a useful backup of all application files.

Answer (score 0):

`/var` is hidden and thus harder to get to. Apple has hidden `~/Library` from the common user for the same reason, makes it harder to foul thing up.